# Playing sound after jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, audio, webforms

I have a following HTML in my web forms like following:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridLanguages" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <a class="audio">
                          <%# Eval("Name") %>
                      <audio  >
                         <source src="<%# "/languages/" + Eval("Path") %>" type="audio/mpeg">
                    </audio>
                     </a>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the function that I'm using to trigger the event:

```
<script>

        $('document').ready(function () {
            $(".audio").click(function (event) {
                console.log("Event triggered"); // this line is shown in console so this part is ok
                var audio = $(this)[0];
            });
        });

   </script>
```

As you can see gridview data source can contain multiple paths to mp3 files that I've loaded successfully. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to when the event is triggered on a element, I'd like to play the corresponding audio file for that which was clicked.
I'm also trying to figure out how to, if the user clicks on another mp3 link, all previous audio files would be stopped and the current one would play... How can I achieve that ?

Can someone help me out ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate all `.audio` element, set `currentTime` to `0`, call `.pause()`; then call `.load()`, `.play()` on `event.target`:`var audio = $(this)[0];`. Note, `document` is an object, not a string

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elems = $(".audio");
        elems.click(function (event) {
            elems.find("audio").each(function() {                 
              this.pause();
              this.currentTime = 0;
            });
            console.log("Event triggered");
            var audio = $(this).find("audio")[0];
            audio.load();
            audio.play();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting this error with your code:Uncaught TypeError: this.pause is not a function. Edit, this one as well: Uncaught TypeError: audio.load is not a function

Comment: @perkes456 See updated post. Did not initially notice that `<audio>` is child element of `.audio` element; added `.find()` at `.each()` and defining `audio` variable

Comment: I think if we are stopping other playing audios, there will only be one audio playing at a time. So no need to iterate on all audio elements.

Comment: @ShaunakD Not certain what you mean?

Comment: I mean to say, we are anyways stopping other audios while playing new. Then there is no need to iterate on all audios and pause them, as only one will be playing at a time. We should be only stopping that audio.